# Android annotation to run on Ui Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

Is it possible to annotate method to run code in UiThread?

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
//my code
}});
```

looks too complex to use it often.

Comment: Did you posted any issue for forum related to your PanoramaSample project? . I checked on the git forum issue list but not able to find anything over there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at the AndroidAnnotations project. They use a annotations. As far as i know it is what you want. It uses compile time code generation http://code.google.com/p/androidannotations/

---

#### Note:

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/UiThread.html) the `@UiThread` annotation only denotes that the given class/method **should** run on the UI thread. It does **NOT** mean using this annotation will call your method on the UI thread.

Comment: Watch out for the correct import, both the AndroidAnnotations and support annotation are called @UiThread

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** this answer is not relevant any more. You can annotate with [`@UiThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/UiThread.html).

<s>According to Google IO 2015, `@UiThread` is the annotation you are looking for. There will be actually four new:
http://robovm.com/google-io-summary-whats-new-in-android-development-tools/ (under New Support Annotations).</s>

Sadly, they are not live yet. When they will be live, they will pop up in here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/package-summary.html

Comment: According to the docs it says "Denotes that the annotated method or constructor should only be called on the UI thread." So it's only for documentations purposes.

Answer (score 0):

@UiThreadTest seems to work now. I'm sure it will be deprecated for the real thing soon, so caveat emptor.